# Display toast messages after redirecting to URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony1

I am trying to submit a form and upon submitting the form the page should be redirected to a different URL. This is working fine, BUT the toast message appears right after the user hits SAVE button and then the page redirects to a different URL and the toast message vanishes.

However I want to redirect to display toast message after getting into the redirect URL and stay there for about 1 second. Here is my javascript code.

```
function submitForm(event) {
        if ($('#expenseTypeAddForm').valid()) {
            preloaderOption.On();

            var url = $('#expenseTypeAddForm').attr('action');
            ohrmAjaxHandler.url = url;
            ohrmAjaxHandler.type = 'POST';
            ohrmAjaxHandler.dataType = 'JSON';
            ohrmAjaxHandler.data = $('#expenseTypeAddForm').serialize();
            ohrmAjaxHandler.success = saveExpenseTypeSuccess;
            ohrmAjaxHandler.call();

        }
        else {
            console.log("Form is not valid");
        }
    };

    function saveExpenseTypeSuccess(data) {
        if (data['redirectUrl']) {
            window.location = (data['redirectUrl']);
        }

        preloaderOption.Off();
        toast.show(data['state'], data['responseMsg']);
    }
```

Comment: you'll need some kind of persistent storage, you could devise something like that using cookies, or sessions

Comment: here, http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html#flash-messages you could implement this, flash messages

Comment: In Symfony 1.x, toast messages are called 'flash' messages.  Here is the relevant chapter on how to set them up: http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/jobeet/1_4/en/13?orm=Doctrine From the doc: "A flash is an ephemeral message stored in the user session that will be automatically deleted after the very next request. It is very useful when you need to display a message to the user after a redirect."

Comment: Hi, @Ghost, yeah earlier I implemented the success messages using Symfony flash messages. But now I'm sending ajax calls. Can I still use flash messages with ajax calls?

Comment: @MadhukaHarith yes you could

Answer (score 2):

You can use session of javascript

`sessionStorage.setItem("showmsg", "1");`

and check if session exists then display message on other page and then reset the session

```
if(sessionStorage.getItem("showmsg")=='1'){
alert('success');
sessionStorage.removeItem("showmsg");
}
```